# Spring MVC date binding returns null value

Tags: spring, date, spring-mvc, data-binding

I created one time-stamp member in class  and storing it in database. When I try to update its value becomes null but able to see its value in UI.

I used init binder for conversion of string to date but it is not working, please help me.

**CNTC.java**

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

    /**
     * Cntc generated by hbm2java
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cntc", catalog = "ecable")
    public class Cntc implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Integer cntcId;
        private String mobNo;
        private String altMobNo;
        private String emailId;
        private String crtId;
        private Date crtTs;
        private String updId;
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.z")
        private Date updTs;
        private Set<Addr> addrs = new HashSet<Addr>(0);



        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "CNTC_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getCntcId() {
            return this.cntcId;
        }

        public void setCntcId(Integer cntcId) {
            this.cntcId = cntcId;
        }

        @Column(name = "MOB_NO", nullable = false, length = 500)
        public String getMobNo() {
            return this.mobNo;
        }

        public void setMobNo(String mobNo) {
            this.mobNo = mobNo;
        }

        @Column(name = "ALT_MOB_NO", nullable = false, length = 500)
        public String getAltMobNo() {
            return this.altMobNo;
        }

        public void setAltMobNo(String altMobNo) {
            this.altMobNo = altMobNo;
        }

        @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = false, length = 1000)
        public String getEmailId() {
            return this.emailId;
        }

        public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
            this.emailId = emailId;
        }

        @Column(name = "CRT_ID", nullable = false, length = 200)
        public String getCrtId() {
            return this.crtId;
        }

        public void setCrtId(String crtId) {
            this.crtId = crtId;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "CRT_TS", nullable = false, length = 0)
        public Date getCrtTs() {
            return this.crtTs;
        }

        public void setCrtTs(Date crtTs) {
            this.crtTs = crtTs;
        }

        @Column(name = "UPD_ID", length = 200)
        public String getUpdId() {
            return this.updId;
        }

        public void setUpdId(String updId) {
            this.updId = updId;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "UPD_TS", length = 0)
        public Date getUpdTs() {
            return this.updTs;
        }

        public void setUpdTs(Date updTs) {
            this.updTs = updTs;
        }

    }
```

**Controller binding**

```
    @InitBinder
    public final void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }
```

**Date displayed in UI**

```
2015-02-11 08:35:18.0
```

This is date format I am able to see in UI but when I try to update its value becomes null in spring data binding object, please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format that you're using is wrong, when you're declaring a [month pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you should be using capitalized `M`, so it should be

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

the *@DateTimeFormat* will also convert a string to Date, so your *initBinder* is not needed and you should delete it.

Note that the pattern must fit the format of the date in the request, the posted pattern fits for example a following format `"2010-07-04 00:00:00"`, I'm mentioning this 'cause your binder and the pattern inside the *@DateTimeFormat* are different, you should set the one corresponding to your request parameter format